# How to maximize a lebesgue integral with respect to a probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm relatively new to measure theory, and I think this is a simple question.

I'm looking for strategies/techniques to solve optimization problems of the form:

$$\mu^* = argmax_{\mu} 
\int_X\int_X f(x,x') d\mu(x) d\mu(x')$$

In plain english: Given some function $f$ I want to find a probability measure on $X$ which maximizes the value of this lebesgue integral. Since $\mu$ has to be a probability measure, there are additional constraints that $\mu(E) \geq 0$ and $\int d\mu(x) = 1$.

I attempted to solve this by considering a simpler version and using Riemann integration, which I'm more familiar with:

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, then we need to find $p^* = argmax_p \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)p(x)dx$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x)dx = 1$, $p(x) \geq 0, \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Wouldn't this just be $p^*(x_0) = \delta(x_0)$ for $x_0 = argmax_x f(x)$? I'm unsure about this simplified solution, and even more unsure about how it relates to the more general expression above involving the lebesgue integral.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem seems reminiscent of maximal transport, which is currently an area of open research.  But I can't seem to reduce it to an optimal transport problem, so maybe it's easier than I think.

Your analysis of the simplified problem "find $\mu$ maximizing $\int{f\,d\mu}$" is correct: the maximizer is $\delta_M$, where $M=\operatorname{argmax}{f}$.  But this is because the change from 2D to 1D removed an essential element of the problem.

Consider the problem "Find $\mu$ maximizing $\int_{[0,1]^2}{x(1-y)\,d^2\mu(x,y)}$."  The maximum of $x(1-y)$ is $1$, attained at $(x,y)=(1,0)$, but by Fubini \begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]^2}{x(1-y)\,d\mu^2(x,y)}&=\left(\int_0^1{x\,d\mu(x)}\right)\int_0^1{(1-y)\,d\mu(y)} \\
&=\left(\int_0^1{x\,d\mu(x)}\right)\left(1-\int_0^1{x\,d\mu(x)}\right) \\
&\leq\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*} just by maximizing $z(1-z)$ over $[0,1]$.  And of course most $f$ do not factorize in this way.

One (relatively) nice case is when $\mu$ is absolutely continuous.  Then one can apply calculus of variations: let $d\mu(x)=\psi(x)\,dx$, so that $$\int{f(x,y)\,d\mu^2(x,y)}=\int{\psi(x)f(x,y)\psi(y)\,d^2(x,y)}\tag{1}$$  For simplicity, suppose $0<\psi<1$ on $X$; then (1) is maximized when, for every bounded function $\phi$ supported on $X$, \begin{align*}
0&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\int{(\psi+t\phi)(x)f(x,y)(\psi+t\phi)(y)\,d^2(x,y)}\right|_{t=0} \\
&=\int{(\phi(x)f(x,y)\psi(y)+\psi(x)f(x,y)\phi(y))\,d^2(x,y)}
\end{align*}  Since $L^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^2$, this implies $0=\int{(f(y,x)\psi(x)+\psi(x)f(x,y))\,dx}$ for a.e. $y$.  Depending on your formula for $f$, you might be able to then conclude the form of $\psi$.

If you can't assume smoothness, then a good place to start might be convex combinations of atomic measures and absolutely continuous ones.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! One question: I understand how you dropped $\varphi$ because the previous statement is true for every bounded function $\varphi$. But I don't quite understand what this has to do with $L^\infty$ being dense in $L^2$. Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: @JoshBone: Let $e_a(b)=\int{a(x)b(x)\,dx}$.  In my answer, I have a certain $a$; I know that $e_a(b)=0$ for any bounded $b$ (i.e. $b\in L^{\infty}$), and I want to show that $a=0$.  Well, $e_a$ is continuous in w.r.t. the $L^2$ norm.  So $\ker{(e_a)}$ is closed; if the kernel contains a dense subspace, then it is all of $L^2$.  But if $a\neq0$, then $e_a(a)>0$, so the kernel can only contain a dense subspace when $a=0$.